# supercsv is working too slow on linux machine

Tags: supercsv

I am using supercsv for downloading data as csv. This is working too slow for me is takes 20 30 minutes to download data on Linux machine. CPU usage exceeded to 109% is there any solution to increase performance. The code is given below i am using csvbeanwriter

Comment: Can you post the complete code instead of a random snippet? I'm a Super CSV dev and the only code I recognise is `CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE`. What are you trying to achieve and what have you tried?

Comment: hi,i have posted complete code have a look.

Comment: Hmm ok, I'd look at the Hibernate logging and make sure it's not doing lots of lazy fetching. It looks like you're using a really old version of Super CSV (1.51?), so you might want to upgrade and stick with Super CSV's bean population (it will be faster than BeanUtils). You really need to profile/debug your app and see where it's spending time. If you've got a really large data set, you might want to consider exporting CSV directly from your database.

Comment: i have upgraded my supercsv version from 1.52 to 2.0.1 but for large data like 25000 rows it also takes 25 to 30 min .